# Jsoup не видит тег link при парсинге RSS

Tags: jsoup, android, rss

Jsoup не видит тег link при парсинге RSS, точнее, возвращает пустые значения. Как исправить? Пытался сделать через `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser())`, но он возвращает строку с адресом.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("link")`

Comment: И куда же возвращается строчка с адресом? Не вижу, чтобы тут были какие-то строчки (String).